# How to transform DataTable to CSV without Encoding Problem

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, ado.net, export-to-csv

I have a code about which transforms DataTable to CSV file. There is no problem about it. But when i look to CSV file some Turkish Characters (ISO-8859-9) seems wrong. I have to solve encoding problem;

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                          Select(column => column.ColumnName);
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field =>
              string.Concat("\"", field.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\""));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
        }

        File.WriteAllText("Gecisler" + Tarih + ".csv", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Try selecting an appropriate Encoding for the file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_WriteAllText_System_String_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_

Comment: Ok I got it, there is no problem with code, I have to set Encoding of Excel. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "rolling" your own CSV writer, I recommend using [Pnyx](http://pnyx.me/example/so/58290792) library. It gracefully handles file encoding, Unix/windows newlines, and [RFC 4180](http://pnyx.me/txt/rfc4180.txt) compliant CSV formatting.

Here is an example using its fluent API (replace some_xxx with actual values):

```
        string Tarih = "some_value";
        DataTable dt = some_data();

        using (Pnyx p = new Pnyx())
        {
            p.setSettings(outputEncoding: Encoding.GetEncoding(some_encoding()));
            p.readRowFunc(
                source: () => dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(dataRow => dataRow.ItemArray.Select(obj => obj.ToString()).ToList()),
                header: () => dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => column.ColumnName).ToList()
            );
            p.writeCsv("Gecisler" + Tarih + ".csv");
        }
```

Full disclosure: I am a contributor to the library.